# Git difftool -- how to ignore images?

Tags: git, difftool, filemerge

i'm a git / osx / unix newbie but in my current job, i'm using them all.  i run "git difftool" a lot to compare changes in a commit, but any time it runs into an image, i get an error from FileMerge and i have to make a few unnecessary clicks to skip it....sometimes 10 or 20 times for any commit.

i looked but haven't seen any easy way to ignore images during a diff?